# Write a function that takes list and returns list for every element where position of single element is exchanged with product of all other elements

Tags: python, list, numpy

My code doesn't empty the return list to only return a list with a single element being the product of all others. Why is that so? I would prefer a solution without numpy

```
def multiList(arr):
    print(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        results = arr
        product = np.prod(arr)
        results[i] = product / arr[i]
        print(results) 


for a in range(2):
    multiList(np.random.randint(100, size=5))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[69 78 62 73 23]
[8119644      78      62      73      23]
[     8119644 845238701112           62           73           23]
[          8119644      845238701112 72752045220088720                73
                23]
[          8119644      845238701112 72752045220088720 60699456787624600
                23]
[            8119644        845238701112   72752045220088720
   60699456787624600 -230203944488679872]
[59 32 31 14 53]
[736064     32     31     14     53]
[     736064 16930944128          31          14          53]
[             736064         16930944128 -273904390770811136
                  14                  53]
[             736064         16930944128 -273904390770811136
 -450116849674523200                  53]
[             736064         16930944128 -273904390770811136
 -450116849674523200   -7087115240883103]
```

Expected:

```
[69 78 62 73 23]
[8119644      78      62      73      23]
[68        7182762    62      73      23]
[69           78    9036378   73      23]
etc...
```

Comment: Why are you doing `product = 1` and `results = []` just to immediately overwrite them?

Comment: That was my first "fix" that didn't work out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](/q/2612802/4518341) For NumPy arrays, see [User Guide > Copies and views > Copy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html#copy).

Comment: OK, you can remove those lines then; they effectively do nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I am here

Comment: Seems like the question was closed because the title doesn't match the body, meaning it's not clear if you want a solution to the specific problem you're having or if you're open to another solution like Quang's. You can [edit] to clarify. Check out [ask] if you want tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: Hi I solved the issue myself by setting ```results = arr.copy()```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged numpy, let's try some numpy magic:

```
# sample data
a = np.array([69,78,62,73,23])


# the product of all elements
prod = a.prod()

# the output array
out = np.vstack([a]*len(a))

# we only need to modify the diagonal of the output array 
# first let's spawn the coordiates
x,y = np.ogrid[:len(a), :len(a)]

# the diagonal is just x==y; we update this diagonal
# the new values are the product of all elements divided by the corresponding elements
out[x==y] = prod/a

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[ 8119644       78       62       73       23]
 [      69  7182762       62       73       23]
 [      69       78  9036378       73       23]
 [      69       78       62  7674732       23]
 [      69       78       62       73 24358932]]
```

Comment: What is an ogrid?

Comment: [np.ogrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) is a convenience function to give you a pair of coordinate arrays. You can use this to manipulate  some ndarray as in this answer.

Comment: Easier approach IMO: `out = np.repeat(a[None], len(a), axis=0) ; np.fill_diagonal(out, np.prod(a)/a)` ;)